# Makefile rule using the automatic variable $^ without dependencies

Tags: variables, makefile, prerequisites

I learnt from the GNU Make manual that the sign    `$^`    is an automatic variable which represents the names of all the prerequisites. However I fell upon a makefile like this one:

```
SVR_OBJECT_FILES =      server.o\
                        server_func.o

CLT_OBJECT_FILES =      client.o

CFLAGS =                -Wall -Werror -W


CC =                    gcc

all:                   client/client server/serveur

client/client:         $(CLT_OBJECT_FILES)

server/serveur:        $(SVR_OBJECT_FILES)

client/client server/serveur:
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f client/client server/serveur *.o
```

Which works fine so my question is :
 How can the command below can link the right object files while the $^  variable is refering no preprerequisites at all. (the rule has no prerequisites)

```
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$^` contains all the prerequisites of the target, not just the ones that are mentioned with the rule itself. The same file can appear as a target several times in rules with no commands:

```
sometarget: dependency1
…
sometarget: dependency2
        assemble -o $@ $^
…
sometarget: dependency3
```

The dependencies of `sometarget` are `dependency1`, `dependency2` and `dependency3`, and when the `assemble` command is invoked by `make sometarget`, it will receive all three as arguments.

Here, `$^` will contain all `$(CLT_OBJECT_FILES)` or `$(SRV_OBJECT_FILES)` depending on which target the command is executed for.